# Double contraction between 2nd and 4th rank tensor

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, tensors

I would like to compute the double dot product between a 2nd and 4th rank tensor in mathematica $A_{kl}A_{ijkl}$

$if \, A_{kl}=\begin{pmatrix} 1& 0 & 0\\ 0 & 1 & 0\\ 0&0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \, and \, \, A_{ijkl}=\begin{pmatrix} 1 &0 &0 &0 &1 &0& 0& 0& 1\\ 0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0\\ 0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0& 0&\\ 0& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0&\\ 1& 0& 0& 0& 1& 0& 0& 0& 1&\\ 0& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0&\\ 0& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0&\\ 0& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0\\ 1& 0& 0& 0& 1& 0& 0& 0& 1 \end{pmatrix} then \, A_{kl}A_{ijkl} = \begin{pmatrix} 3&0 &0 \\ 0 &3 &0 \\ 0 &0 &3 \end{pmatrix}$

Can anyone give me a hand with this?

Best Regards

Comment: I cannot see it that the big matrix on the right is a 4-rank tensor.

Answer (score 2):

I assume your matrices are just an identity and its tensor product with itself reshaped into a matrix:

```
A = IdentityMatrix[3];
B = ArrayReshape[TensorProduct[A, A], {9, 9}];
```

If you treat them like this, then it's only one contraction:

```
TensorContract[TensorProduct[A, B], {{3, 4}}]
```

But I think this would be more faithful to your mathematical notation of contracting twice:

```
TensorContract[TensorProduct[A, A, A], {{1, 5}, {2, 6}}]
```

Comment: @ManuelOliveira You can take products of tensors of any rank with `TensorProduct`. Then you just contract appropriate indices with `TensorContract`. This is almost as general as it can get already.

Comment: Yes, `TensorProduct`-`TensorContract` combo should be the general way.

Comment: @ManuelOliveira Correct, tensor product essentially concatenates indices, so you get $klijkl$. Index $k$ is in position 1 and 5, index $l$ is in position 2 and 6.

Comment: Understood! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
A = {{1, 0, 0},
     {0, 1, 0},
     {0, 0, 1}};
B = {{1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1},
     {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
     {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
     {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
     {1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1},
     {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
     {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
     {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
     {1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1}};

Partition[B.Flatten[A], 3]
(*    {{3, 0, 0},
       {0, 3, 0},
       {0, 0, 3}}    *)
```

Comment: what is for the case: Double contraction of two 4th tensors?

Answer (score 0):

For arbitrary rank tensors with any number of contractions between them, you can use `Flatten` and then `Dot` to get what you are after. If you are using numeric tensors (packed arrays), this might be quicker than the `Tensor` commands.

The general idea is that you can take a tensor $A_{kl}$ and then `Flatten` the $kl$ indices into a single multi-index $\alpha = (kl)$. You can then do the same with $B_{ijkl}$ (I'm calling it $B$ instead of $A$ here). You then have
$$B_{ijkl} A_{kl} = B_{ij\alpha}A_{\alpha}$$
so that it is a standard dot product on the $\alpha$ index.

Let's start by defining a rank 2 and a rank 4 tensor (for example) of dimensions $3\times3$ and $3\times3\times3\times3$:

```
(* Subscript[A, kl] *)
A = RandomReal[10, {3, 3}];
(* Subscript[B, ijkl] *)
B = RandomReal[10, {3, 3, 3, 3}];
```

We then use `Flatten` on the $kl$ indices

```
A$flat = Flatten[A, {{1,2}}];
B$flat = Flatten[B, {{1}, {2}, {3, 4}}];
```

Note that the behaviour of `Flatten` is that `{{1}, {2}, {3, 4}}` says that the flattened object has indices given by {"1st index of original","2nd index of original","3rd and 4th index of original"}. These are now rank 1 and rank 3 tensors $A_\alpha$ and $B_{ij\alpha}$ of dimensions $9$ and $3\times3\times9$. We can then use the usual dot product

```
B$flat.A$flat
```

which gives a $3\times3$ dimensional rank two tensor. Or putting it all together

```
(* Subscript[A, kl] *)
A = RandomReal[10, {3, 3}];
(* Subscript[B, ijkl] *)
B = RandomReal[10, {3, 3, 3, 3}];
(* Flatten and take dot product *)
Flatten[B, {{1}, {2}, {3, 4}}].Flatten[A, {{1, 2}}]
```

Note that you could also swap the order of the dot product as

```
Flatten[A, {{1, 2}}].Flatten[B, {{3, 4}, {1}, {2}}]
```

where the `Flatten` on $B$ is used to transpose the $\alpha=(kl)$ indices to get $B_{\alpha i j}$ instead. I hope this illustrates what `Flatten` is doing.

You can also do this for more complicated contractions such as
$$A_{k i m}B_{j k l m}$$
which gives a tensor with indices $(i j l)$ as the result. The code for this would be

```
(* Subscript[A, ikm] *)
A = RandomReal[10, {3, 3, 3}];
(* Subscript[B, ijklm] *)
B = RandomReal[10, {3, 3, 3, 3, 3}];
(* Flatten and take dot product *)
Flatten[A, {{2}, {1, 3}}].Flatten[B, {{2, 4}, {1}, {3}}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another ways. Start with theses arrays

```
A = {{1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1}};
B = {{1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 0, 1,
     0, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1}};
AA = ArrayReshape[B, {3, 3, 3, 3}]
```

**1.**

```
ArrayReshape[AA, {3, 3, 9}].ArrayReshape[A, {9}]
```

**2.**

```
ArrayReshape[B, {3, 3, 9}].ArrayReshape[A, {9}]
```